# Spring Cloud Stream 3.0 with kafka consumer in batch mode fetches single record in list instead of more

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Trying to consume kafka messages in batch mode using Spring Cloud Stream 3.0.

Consumer receives a list containing single record, instead of more.

below is the yml , consumer coded used

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        process-in-0:
          destination: person-command
          consumer:
#            maxAttempts: 1
            batch-mode: true
            properties:
               maxPollRecords: 10
               minFetchBytes: 5000
               fetchMaxWaitMs: 1000
```

Consumer code

```
@Transactional
@Bean
public Function<List<PersonEvent>, List<PersonEvent>> process() {


    return pel ->{

        List<Person> lstPerson = new ArrayList<Person>();
        List<PersonEvent> lstPersonEvent = new ArrayList<PersonEvent>();    
        for (PersonEvent personEvent : pel) {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setName(personEvent.getName());
            lstPerson.add(person);
            personEvent.setType("PersonSaved");
            lstPersonEvent.add(personEvent);

        }
        logger.info("Person Size {}"+lstPerson.size());
        Iterable<Person> savedPerson = repository.saveAll(lstPerson);
        logger.info("Saved Person Size {}"+lstPerson.size());

        return lstPersonEvent;
    };
    }
```

output:
Logs show one record is fetched in a list, instead we need a batch of 10 records

```
2020-01-05 15:11:49.044  INFO 29590 --- [container-0-C-1] ication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d65e615 : Person Size {}1
2020-01-05 15:11:49.054  INFO 29590 --- [container-0-C-1] ication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d65e615 : Saved Person Size {}1
2020-01-05 15:11:50.045  INFO 29590 --- [container-0-C-1] ication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d65e615 : Person Size {}1
2020-01-05 15:11:50.053  INFO 29590 --- [container-0-C-1] ication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6d65e615 : Saved Person Size {}1
```

Comment: Note: you should be using a comma in the log statement, not a plus. And the maxPollRecords is an upper limit, not a lower one

Comment: Also, it appears you're using a repository, thus a database... Kafka Connect is generally a more appropriate framework for that solution

Comment: The properties are not set properly; see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such property `properties` under consumer. In any case, Kafka properties are not common and need to be specified as Kafka-specific.

See [the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_consumer_properties).

Furthermore, Spring Boot knows nothing about arbitrary Kafka properties and won't perform camelCase conversion on them. See [the Kafka Binder documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties).

Try

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        bindings:
          process-in-0:
            consumer:
              configuration:
                max.poll.records: 10
                min.fetch.bytes: 5000
                fetch.max.wait.ms: 1000
```

You can confirm that the properties are set as expected by examining the INFO log put out by the Kafka clients.